# Is it possible to use PodPresets in OpenShift 3.11 (3.7+)?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod, okd

I've installed an OpenShift cluster for testing purposes, and since I'm behind a corporate network, I need to include some Root Certificates in any Pod that wants to make external requests. What can I do to inject those certificates automatically at Pod creation?

I'm running OpenShift Origin (OKD) 3.11 in a local CentOS 7 VM, with a GlusterFS storage provisioning on top of it. I already had multiple issues with the VM itself, which gave me errors when trying to access the network: `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`. I fixed that by adding my corporation root certificates in /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors and by running the `update-ca-trust` command.

When I was running for example the docker-registry deployment in the OpenShift cluster, since the created Pods didn't have access to the host root certificates, they gave again `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` errors when trying to pull images from docker.io. I resolved that by creating a ConfigMap containing all needed root certificates, and mounting them in a volume on the registry deployment config.

I thought I only needed to mount a volume in all deployment configs which want to request the external network. But then I provisioned a Jenkins instance and I realised something new: When a pipeline runs, Jenkins creates a Pod with an adapted agent (example: a Spring Boot app will need a Maven agent). Since I have no control to those created pods, they can't have the mounted volume with all root certificates. So for instance I have a pipeline that runs `helm init --client-only` before releasing my app chart, and this command gives a `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` error, because this pod hasn't the root certificates.

[x509 Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hJcr.png)

I found that a PodPreset could be the perfect way to resolve my problem, but when I enable this feature in the cluster and create the PodPreset, no new pod is populated. I read on the [OpenShift documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/dev_guide/pod_preset.html) that PodPresets are no longer supported as of 3.7, so I think that it could be the reason it is not working.

[OpenShift docs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG6Sb.png)

Here is my PodPreset definition file:

```
kind: PodPreset
apiVersion: settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1
metadata:
  name: inject-certs
spec:
  selector: {}
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/cert1.pem
      name: ca
      subPath: cert1.pem
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/cert2.pem
      name: ca
      subPath: cert2.pem
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/cert3.pem
      name: ca
      subPath: cert3.pem
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/cert4.pem
      name: ca
      subPath: cert4.pem
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/cert5.pem
      name: ca
      subPath: cert5.pem
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs/cert6.pem
      name: ca
      subPath: cert6.pem
  volumes:
    - configMap:
        defaultMode: 420
        name: ca-pemstore
      name: ca
```

I don't know if there is any way to make PodPresets work on OpenShift 3.11, or if there is another solution to inject certs file like this in created pods. This would be really great.

Comment: Hi, that's true , podpreset is depricated, instead you can use muttating webhooks do this job

Comment: Here some reference https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#experimenting-with-admission-webhooks ,

Comment: or you can use OPA do to it for you https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kubernetes-admission-control

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer ! I'll check it out right now

Answer (score 0):

The RedHat COP on GitHub contains a project with a podpresent admission webhook controller you can use:
https://github.com/redhat-cop/podpreset-webhook

basically you deploy that project and change the apiVersion in your PodPresent to `apiVersion: redhatcop.redhat.io/v1alpha1`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24503694)

Comment: @juanlumn i didn't link a answer - i linked a project that provides a way to use a feature that is deprecated and removed in openshift. If that project is gone this answer will be useless too.

I'm with you that answers that link only answers are bad in general, but i linked to a project and without that this answer has no value. Copying the entire readme over wouldn't help either as it gets outdated fast. I'm not sure how i could improve this answer to be honest - but would appreciate suggestions.